# Insert and retrieval order in couchbase

Tags: json, xml, sorting, couchbase

Is there a way we can maintain the insertion and retrieval order same for json document.
eg.

```
config : {
“x” : {
“p” : 2,
“a” : 3
},
“a” : {
“b” = 23,
“l” = 56
}
}
```

When I store above doc and try to retrieve the same, the order of elements is getting changed.
I want the ordering to remain as is.

I understand its an object and there is no guarantee for the ordering.
But my use case is to take this doc and covert to an xml and load on the system. If ordering is not same xml load fails.

Note: I don’t want to push xml in db.

Comment: Which language/ client SDK are you using? How are you retrieving the document?

Comment: Hi, I am using Springboot couchbase maven plugin to retrieve the doc

Answer (score 1):

If you're using N1QL, the fields you get in each JSON object will always be produced in alphabetic order. That's just how the serialization code works. There's no way to change it in the query engine itself.

Answer (score 1):

With the Couchbase Java SDK, you can access the raw unprocessed document contents as a String using `RawJsonDocument` like this:

```
String docId = ...;
RawJsonDocument rawDoc = bucket.get(RawJsonDocument.create(docId));
String json = rawDoc.content(); // Unprocessed. Parse it however you want.
```

Answer (score 0):

This will probably depend on how you are converting the JSON to XML. If Newtonsoft is involved, for instance, you can use the [`JsonProperty` attribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyOrder.htm) and specify an order.

Comment: Newtonsoft maintains an extra property for ordering...but doing so will not be feasible in my case as many nodes are involved and there are many nesting.